# AngularJS ui-router: ui-sref and directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, directive

I have such html:

```
<span ui-sref="{{detailsArt(art.Id)}}" check-val></span>
```

and in my directive check-val i have:

```
link: function(scp, el, attr) {
  el.bind('click', function(event) {
    //some logic with if:
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

and it's not working with ui-sref(

when i'm using `$state.go('detailsArt', {artId: art.Id})` this directive is working fine.

Is it possible to use ui-sref with directive click handler, and how?

Answer (score 1):

Because it should be: `ui-sref="detailsArt({artId : art.Id})"`
And of course you need an anchor tag `a` as said by Pankaj

```
<a ui-sref="detailsArt({artId: art.Id})" check-val></a>
```

Comment: with ui-sref="detailsArt({artId : art.Id}) it works too